# CKEditor - Make certain text read only

Tags: javascript, plugins, jquery-plugins, editor, ckeditor

Calling CKEditor gurus to this question. I have a need to make only certain areas within my textbox readonly. These areas will be text and image URLS that will be enclosed by a span tag with a predefined class type. I have checked the documentation but cant seem to find anything that will help me accomplish this. They all make the entire textbox go read only.
I have heard that there are hacks that can make this work, but Im not sure which way to go about doing it. I am fairly new to this, so please bear with me if my question seems absurd.

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

Use [widgets](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets).

Take a look on [some samples](http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets) first and then focus on [Placeholder plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder) (based on widgets), which does pretty much what you'd like to have. You can either customize it or create something new, referring to existing code and [official guides](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_intro).

Note: You need CKEditor 4.3+.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like the entire placeholder can be deleted though. Is my early observation correct or can that be controlled too ? I want to be able to programatically add placeholders.

Comment: @oleq I too have been looking for content that cannot be removed. I can make a readonly widget but I can remove this from the content by hitting backspace. Is it possible to override this in some way?

Comment: I just created a Placeholder and it is read only; but yes i can delete it, too and that is not good. it will just have to do for now.